# Powershell Script "$dirs"

Tags: powershell

So I do not have a degree or any formal training in any programming language but my job has had me slowly learn the basics of SQL and I have now been given a new task at work. The previous person in charge of this task ran powershell scripts to combine and rename PDFs. I get the macro level of how this all works. The script sets a loop through the parent directory into all the children directory concatenates the PDFs using PDFtk Server then renames the combined PDFs to child directory they are named in. However, I cannot figure out how to specify the dirs (I think thats the term). As it stands now I can only successfully run the powershell script in the folder in which Console2 is located.

```
$path = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 

Function mergeFiles 
{ 
# Loop through all directories 
$dirs = dir $path -Recurse | Where { $_.psIsContainer -eq $true }
$cmd = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe'
$In1 = 'A.pdf'
$In2 = 'B.pdf'
$Out1 = 'C.pdf'
Foreach ($dir In $dirs)
```

This is the first part of the merge files function. Can someone help me figure out how to identify a specfic "dirs"? (Like if I had the PDF in a folder on my desktop)

Comment: Are you talking about the `$path` variable?

Comment: Please be more specific in your title. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think it's the path variable but I'm not entirely sure. I just want to know how to set a specific directory that the powershell script is looking in to run the loop of combining files. Currently the script will only look in all the directories in the console 2 parent directory (where I have console 2 installed on my C drive)  I.e it will only look for subdirectories from C:\Console_2. How do I get it to look at something like C:\Users\JC\Desktop\PDF

Answer (score 2):

The location that is populating the directory it will search based on the location of your script, based on this line:

```
$path = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition` is the full path to the running script and the command `Split-Path -parent` will return the parent directory. You could just change that line to be the the location you want i.e.:

```
$path = 'C:\Users\JC\Desktop\PDF'
```

but you probably don't want to hardcode that path. What you want to do is add the path as an input argument to the script. To do that, add the following to the top of your script:

```
PARAM($path)
```

Then when you invoke your script, you just pass the path you are interested in:

```
.\theScript.ps1 C:\Users\JC\Desktop\PDF
```

You can then get more advanced and specify a default value, for example, if you want the default to be the location the script is run:

```
PARAM($path = '.')
```

Comment: Thanks mate. When I get into work tomorrow I should have alot more luck with this now